# DNS resolution fails for hostname mapped to 192.168 address on some machines

Tags: dns

I have a domain name mapped to a local subnet address so I can easily test across devices (test.internetdancefloor.com maps to 192.168.1.88 or something like that).  This address works from my Windows machines, however it does not work from my android devices or Mac.  When I run nslookup on my mac, DNS fails:

```
users-mbp:~ user$ nslookup internetdancefloor.com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   internetdancefloor.com
Address: 174.127.248.98

users-mbp:~ user$ nslookup test.internetdancefloor.com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find test.internetdancefloor.com: No answer
```

Any idea why nslookup for test.internetdancefloor.com succeeds for some machines but not others?

My hypothesis is that the DNS client on mac and android devices rejects local subnet IP addresses, because I added a traditional DNS entry (version.internetdancefloor.com) later and it works fine across devices.  I haven't been able to very this hypothesis otherwise.

@Alex:

```
users-MacBook-Pro:videoplayer user$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
#
# Mac OS X Notice
#
# This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
# or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
# this Mac OS X system.
#
# This file is automatically generated.
#
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Update:

We observed that the Mac is using the router directly as a DNS server, rather than the DNS servers the router is configured to use.  My windows machine does not use the router (192.168.1.1) as the DNS server, but rather picks up the static IPs the router is configured to use (via DHCP I guess).

When I use nslookup from my PC but select the DNS server, I see that the router is the one failing the DNS requests and not the upstream DNS servers.  When I don't specify a DNS server, it does not default to 192.168.1.1 but rather uses the upstream DNS server directly (208.76.152.1)

```
C:\src> nslookup test.internetdancefloor.com
Server:  DNSresolver-A.spectrumnet.us
Address:  208.76.152.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    test.internetdancefloor.com
Address:  192.168.1.88

C:\src> nslookup test.internetdancefloor.com 208.76.152.1
Server:  DNSresolver-A.spectrumnet.us
Address:  208.76.152.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    test.internetdancefloor.com
Address:  192.168.1.88

C:\src> nslookup test.internetdancefloor.com 192.168.1.1
Server:  unknown
Address:  192.168.1.1

*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for test.internetdancefloor.com
```

It seems unnatural to configure my android and Mac devices to use a particular DNS server, though I suppose that would work.  Maybe my router is filtering certain DNS results that point to the same subnet, and that can be undone.  I wonder why my Mac/Android devices choose 192.168.1.1 for their DNS server?  Those devices are on a wireless connection while my PCs are wired, so perhaps its a wireless/wired difference.

Comment: Are the failing machines using the DNS server that hosts the internal zone for DNS? It would appear that they're not.

Comment: For some reason it is looking at 192.168.1.1 as your DNS server for those devices. Is that your router?

Comment: These android devices connect to your network?  If they are then it should work.  If they are not then the reason its not working is because you have not configured port forwarding.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I don't know what you mean by internal zone

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie yes 192.168.1.1 is my router.

Comment: @Ramhound yes all devices are on the 192.168.1.x subnet, and can reach each other by static IP

Comment: Can you post the results of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` on your mac please?

Comment: When you stated `I have a domain name mapped to a local subnet address` I assumed that to mean that you have a DNS server on your internal network that hosts the `internetdancefloor.com` DNS zone and that is where you created the DNS records. Is that correct?

Comment: @joeqwerty He has an external DNS provider. You can actually do an nslookup on test.internetdancefloor.com and it pulls the 192.168.1.81 ip.

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie thanks for taking a look, I added the cat you requested

Comment: Check the settings on the DHCP server on your router to see if it is giving out 192.168.1.1 as a DNS server.

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie thanks Alex, that led to a solution which I'm putting as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @alex-mckenzie for leading me to the answer.

My wireless router was telling clients (via DHCP) to use it as the DNS proxy server.  For some reason that router wouldn't resolve IP addresses within the local subnet.  The router software is TomatoUSB.  There is a DHCP configuration setting "Use internal DNS" enabled.  Once I disabled it, clients connecting via DHCP would use the upstream DNS servers directly.

I've noticed that DNS requests often fail the first time I hit a domain, I'm hoping that issue is fixed too.